# What is the definition of BDD?

Tags: testing, tdd, methodology, bdd

BBD is referenced in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260/what-is-tdd) (Karl Seguin's answer). What is BDD?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Behavior Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior_Driven_Development). All info you should need to get you started in that link.

> Behavior Driven Development (or BDD) is an Agile software development technique that encourages collaboration between developers, QA and non-technical or business participants in a software project.

Answer (score 7):

http://behaviour-driven.org/ -

> "BDD is an evolution in the thinking
>   behind Test Driven Development and
>   Acceptance Test Driven Planning."

http://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd

http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2008/11/27/the-truth-about-bdd

http://www.agilejournal.com/articles/columns/column-articles/597-behavior-driven-development-an-evolution-in-testing

http://blog.daveastels.com/files/BDD_Intro.pdf

http://behaviour-driven.org/Introduction

http://eggsonbread.com/2009/07/22/behavior-driven-development-in-a-nutshell/